# How could rgba32f image2d write to textures with GL_RGB32F internal format?

Tags: opengl

When we call glTextureStorage2D, we need to specify the internal format of the texture's storage, and an available option is GL_RGB32F. But there is no rgb32f layout format for image2Ds, so how could I read/write to a texture through image2D?

```
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,&texture);
glTextureStorage2D(texture,1,GL_RGB32F,width,height);
glBindImageTexture(0,texture);
```

```
layout(binding = 0, *) uniform image2D image;
```

Which format should I choose to use at *?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But there is no rgb32f layout format for image2Ds, so how could I read/write to a texture through image2D?

You can't. You cannot use any [3-channel formats with image load/store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Images_in_the_context). Well, technically you can write to the R11_G11_B10 format, but that's about it.