# Compute shader fail to write data to destination texture with format rgba32f

Tags: android, opengl-es, compute-shader

I am new beginner openGL ES, I tried to wrote a very simple sample compute shader to run on Android device.
Below is shader:

```
#version 310 es
precision highp image2D;

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(binding = 1, rgba8) writeonly uniform image2D dstImage;

void main()
{
    ivec2 pixelCoords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    vec4 pixelDst = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    imageStore(dstImage, pixelCoords, pixelDst);
}
```

Above shader work perfectly,dstImage is filled with full RED.
[image]
When I changed rgba8 to rgba32f, dstImage is blank as below image.

```
#version 310 es
precision highp image2D;

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D dstImage;

void main()
{
    ivec2 pixelCoords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    vec4 pixelDst = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    imageStore(dstImage, pixelCoords, pixelDst);
}
```

[image]
Since the problem I have to solve need image with format rgba32f so I want to use compute shader with desImage with format rgba32f.
How can I fill full RED with rgba32f ?

Comment: Possibly related: [How could rgba32f image2d write to textures with GL_RGB32F internal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74794163/295004)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could rgba32f image2d write to textures with GL\_RGB32F internal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74794163/how-could-rgba32f-image2d-write-to-textures-with-gl-rgb32f-internal-format)